# Django deployment with required temporary model data

Tags: python, django, database, deployment

First of all, I am very new to deployment.
I have built a new newspaper project using Django in my windows machine.
It runs fine in localhost.
Now I want to deploy it in **pythonanywhere**.

I am using the default db.sqlite3 as my database.
But in production, I am going to use MySql, (for which they have easy settings and support)

**Problem:**
As a newspaper, my website needs a lot of specialized filtering. To find a single value
I had to, sometimes, use list indexing on filtered data like-(inside get context data):

```
context['main_lead_news']=SingleNews.objects.filter(
                                                    published_date__lte=timezone.now(),
                                                    news_extras__icontains='main_lead_news').order_by('-published_date')[0]
```

As you can see if 'filter' does not find anything, it will raise an error as-
List index out of range. Overall, my code will break without any temporary model data( currently, though most of them are lorem ipsum.) I have populated them before my code was complete. now, how can I deploy my project, as I may not have a chance to populate them online again because of those errors.also my debug will be false, it will be near impossible to run my code without finding errors!

I have two (half!) ideas-

1.somehow upload the sqlite3 database when deploying, then after configuring
MySQL, transfer data from sqlite3 to MySQL on the fly(I don't know how to do that either.)

2.just comment out all the views and URLs and absolute_urls in 'model' except for a
create view and then deploy it. after populating the database by that view, I will delete the commit in Github and update code from there(it seems near-mythical to me).

Are there any conventions for these kinds of situations? what should be my approach?
any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To not get error from django ORM filters, you can use `exists` option like this:

```
news_present = SingleNews.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now(), news_extras__icontains='main_lead_news').exists()

if news_present:
      context['main_lead_news']=SingleNews.objects.filter(
                                                published_date__lte=timezone.now(),
                                                news_extras__icontains='main_lead_news').order_by('-published_date')[0]
```

Or use `count` option like this:

```
news_count = SingleNews.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now(), news_extras__icontains='main_lead_news').count()

if news_count > 0:
      context['main_lead_news']=SingleNews.objects.filter(
                                                published_date__lte=timezone.now(),
                                                news_extras__icontains='main_lead_news').order_by('-published_date')[0]
```

`exists` will not fetch all entries but will check only presence of any value in the filter query. So, it returns `True` or `False`. To read more: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#exists